# Use QTableWidget's sorting abilities for a custom model

Tags: qt, sorting, qtableview, qtablewidget

I have implemented a QTableView and need to sort my table.  However, I like the way QTableWidget handles sorting.  Can I somehow "grab" or use QTableWidget's sortItems() functionality in my QTableView to avoid having to re implement a lot of Qt's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way for sorting `QTableView` would be to use [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). Example from Qt documentation:

```
 QTreeView *treeView = new QTreeView;
 MyItemModel *sourceModel = new MyItemModel(this);
 QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);

 proxyModel->setSourceModel(sourceModel);
 treeView->setModel(proxyModel);
```

Of course, you can replace `QTreeView` with `QTableView` here.